# Delay default hover action using jQuery without plugin?

Tags: jquery, hover, delay

I currently use jQuery to do all sorts of stuff with my navigation menu:

```
    jQuery("ul.menu").closest(".dropdown_fullwidth").add('ul.menu li').add('ul.nav-shop').mouseenter(function () {
    jQuery("#nav-blackout").css("display", "block");
})
    jQuery("ul.menu").mouseleave(function () {
    jQuery("#nav-blackout").css("display", "none");
});
    jQuery("ul.menu").mouseenter(function () {
    jQuery("ul.nav-shop li:nth-child(1)").addClass("is-active");
    jQuery("li.is-active a").next(".has-product-noms").addClass("display-product-noms");    
    if (jQuery(".display-product-noms")[0]){
    jQuery(".nav-banner").css("right", "0");
} else {
    jQuery(".nav-banner").css("right", "9999em");
}
})
    jQuery("ul.menu").mouseleave(function () {
    jQuery("ul.nav-shop li:nth-child(1)").addClass("is-active");
    jQuery("li.is-active a").next(".has-product-noms").addClass("display-product-noms");    
});
    jQuery("li.nav-shop-sub").mouseenter(function () {
    jQuery("li.nav-shop-sub .is-active").removeClass("is-active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("is-active");
    jQuery("li.is-active a").next(".has-product-noms").addClass("display-product-noms");
    if (jQuery(".display-product-noms")[0]){
    jQuery(".nav-banner").css("right", "0");
} else {
    jQuery(".nav-banner").css("right", "9999em");
}
    jQuery("#nav-blackout").css("display", "block");
})
    jQuery("li.nav-shop-sub").mouseleave(function () {
    jQuery("li.is-active a").next(".has-product-noms").removeClass("display-product-noms");
    jQuery(this).removeClass("is-active");
    jQuery("#nav-blackout").css("display", "none");
});
```

It probably isn't pretty but does the job, however I would like to have the top level of my menu (UL - LI) to be delayed upon hover. I.E When you hover over a menu item instead of the css taking immediate effect and the dropdown appearing I would like to delay it by around 250ms so that if the user moves the mouse over the neighboring menu li it won't immediately change / become active.

I have tried using this plugin: https://github.com/john-terenzio/jQuery-Hover-Delay

However despite following the example I can't seem to get it to fire at all. Whether it is just not playing nicely with the rest of the code or plain not working i'm not sure (no errors in console).

Anyone have any ideas? I have already looked at previous/ similar questions but not found anything relevant.

Comment: Did you tried setTimeout on your call?

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure how to use it to be honest the selector would be li.fullwidth

Comment: Can you post function where you call hover function?

Comment: @KondukterCRO I just tried to do: jQuery('li.fullwidth').hover(mouseenter, mouseleave, 250);

Comment: Can you try to make a function that shows menu on hover. Call it for example showMenu. So function showMenu() {//function goes here}. Make setTimeout(showMenu, 250);
So it will call function on hover but you will delay it with setTimeout for 250.

Comment: problem is I don't want/have anything for it to do within the function - purely when you hover over the li I want it to act like you haven't for those 250ms (the css just adds the background colour and a dropdown appears)

Comment: $('li.fullwidth')
  .delay(250)
  .queue(function (show) { 
    $(this).css('background-color', '#000'); 
    show(); 
  });

Did I understand you? Something like this?

Comment: thats the right sort of lines however I'd like the css from the stylesheet to kick in as opposed to adding with jQuery (just a note that the code you put actually didn't have any effect though)

Comment: Can you provide html code that shows menu and jquery that does adding background?

Comment: @KondukterCRO Ignoring any other code essentially I just want a 250ms delay if you hover over li.fullwidth. So it doesn't recognise you have hovered over it until AFTER the 250ms at which point the stylesheet styles take effect...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ef5cojqd/1/

Is that what you want? I ignored everything and on hover you can set delay in js on line 7.

Comment: @KondukterCRO thanks for all your help - that is what I want BUT without jQuery doing the CSS - is that possible?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ef5cojqd/2/
As far as I know it can be done only like this.
I updated my fiddle so jquery only adds class to hovered element. 
Class is defined in css and it contains properties that hovered element needs.
Is that ok or you need something else?

Comment: Kind of - with your help and some tinkering I have now cracked it. THANK YOU so much!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Should I post it as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is fiddle

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/ef5cojqd/2/>
```

If you have some better options please edit so everyone can see.